# Redirecionamento de url

Tags: php, codeigniter, url, route

Bom, faz alguns dias que tenho encontrado alguns problemas em uma tarefa. O que eu preciso fazer é : Verificar se a url está no formato certo, e se ela não estiver, redirecionar para a url correta. Nas outras urls que fiz não tive problemas, mas nesta estou tendo. Enfim, vou tentar explicar o erro da melhor forma.
Eu tenho esta função na minha Model para listar as learnings :

```
 public function get_learning_category_list() {
$categorias = $this->db->select('t1.id, t1.title, t1.metadata, t1.meta_title, t1.description, t1.meta_description, t1.meta_spam, t1.url, t1.alt_img')
        ->from('learning_category t1')
        ->join('learning_rel_category t4', 't1.id = t4.category_id', 'left')
        ->join('learning t2', 't4.learning_id = t2.id', 'left')
        ->join('learning_rel_language t3', 't2.id = t3.learning_id', 'left')
        ->where('t3.language', $this->language)
        ->group_by('t1.id')
        ->get()->result_array();
    foreach($categorias as $c){
        $total = $this->db->select('count(learning_rel_language.learning_id) as total', false)
        ->from('learning')
        ->join('learning_rel_language', 'learning.id = learning_rel_language.learning_id', 'inner')
        ->join('learning_rel_category', 'learning.id = learning_rel_category.learning_id', 'inner')
        ->where('learning_rel_category.category_id', $c['id'])
        ->where('learning_rel_language.language', $this->language)
        ->group_by('learning_rel_language.language')->get()->first_row('array');

        $metadata = json_decode($c['metadata']);
        $tt = $c['title'];
        $url = $c['url'];
        if($this->language != 'pt_br'){
            $tt = $metadata->{$this->language};
            $tt_pt_br = $c['title'];
        }

        $return[] = array('url' => $url, 'title'=>$tt, 'id'=>$c['id'], 'total'=>$total['total'], 'title_pt_br'=>$tt_pt_br);

    }
```

Ela vai me retornar um Array:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [url] => [title] => Cursos sobre como gerar leads qualificados [id] => 2 [total] => 6 [title_pt_br] => ) [1] => Array ( [url] => [title] => Cursos de Social Media Marketing [id] => 3 [total] => 2 [title_pt_br] => )...
```

E ainda na Model tenho esta função que define o formato da url :

```
 public function url_format_category($category, $lang_domin) { //Monta o formato da url
    if (lang('abbr') == 'en_US')
        $lang_domin = 'en/';
    else if (lang('abbr') == 'es_US')
        $lang_domin = 'es/';

    $categorias = $this->learn->get_learning_category_list();
    foreach($categorias as $cat){
        $cat = (object) $cat;
        if($cat->title != '') {
            $return = strtolower(url_title($cat->title)).'-cmdo-'.$cat->id;
        }else{
            $return = 'cursos-de-marketing-digital-online-'.$cat->id;
        }   
    return $return;   
    }
}
```

Até aí tudo certo, ele monta a url com o title e id da Learning. Na minha Controller tenho a função que verifica se a url está correta e a redireciona :

```
    //redirect to real list_route
    if($this->uri->uri_string != $this->learn->url_format_category($category, $lang_domin)) {
        redirect($this->learn->url_format_category(),'location','301');
        exit;
        die($this->learn->url_format_category($category, $lang_domin));

    }
```

É no redirecionamento que ocorre o erro, ele é feito de acordo com o `url_format_category`, mas ele redireciona sempre para o primeiro resultado do Array (Cursos sobre como gerar leads qualificados, ou seja, sempre o mesmo title) independente da página que ele esteja.
Caso não tenha sido claro, posso editar minha pergunta. Agradeço.

Comment: retire a função que define o formato da ur de dentro do model. deixe o model SOMENTE para consultar e retornar os dados do bando de dados. Do jeito que você está fazendo, está desfazendo todo o conceito de MVC. Passe todas as funções para o próprio controller (as faça private) ou crie um helper para isso.

Answer (score 2):

Seu erro está aqui neste código:

```
//redirect to real list_route
    if($this->uri->uri_string != $this->learn->url_format_category($category, $lang_domin)) {
        redirect($this->learn->url_format_category(),'location','301');
        exit;
        die($this->learn->url_format_category($category, $lang_domin));

    }
```

Repare e analise as alterações que fiz:

```
//redirect to real list_route
    if($this->uri->uri_string != $this->learn->url_format_category($category, $lang_domin)) {
        redirect($this->learn->url_format_category(),'location','301');

        die($this->learn->url_format_category($category, $lang_domin));

    }
```

O comando `exit;` estava impedindo o script de seguir a diante, além do mais você tem a função `url_format_category` recebendo parâmetros que nunca são utilizados, para que estão ali então? `url_format_category($category, $lang_domin)`

Então sua função deveria ficar assim:

```
public function url_format_category() { //Monta o formato da url
    if (lang('abbr') == 'en_US')
        $lang_domin = 'en/';
    else if (lang('abbr') == 'es_US')
        $lang_domin = 'es/';

    $categorias = $this->learn->get_learning_category_list();
    foreach($categorias as $cat){
        $cat = (object) $cat;
        if($cat->title != '') {
            $return = strtolower(url_title($cat->title)).'-cmdo-'.$cat->id;
        } else {
            $return = 'cursos-de-marketing-digital-online-'.$cat->id;
        }   
    return $return;   
    }
}
```

E o seu model assim:

```
public function get_learning_category_list() {
    $categorias = $this->db->select('t1.id, t1.title, t1.metadata, t1.meta_title, t1.description, t1.meta_description, t1.meta_spam, t1.url, t1.alt_img')
        ->from('learning_category t1')
        ->join('learning_rel_category t4', 't1.id = t4.category_id', 'left')
        ->join('learning t2', 't4.learning_id = t2.id', 'left')
        ->join('learning_rel_language t3', 't2.id = t3.learning_id', 'left')
        ->where('t3.language', $this->language)
        ->group_by('t1.id')
        ->get()->result_array();

    $return =  array();

    foreach($categorias as $c){
        $total = $this->db->select('count(learning_rel_language.learning_id) as total', false)
            ->from('learning')
            ->join('learning_rel_language', 'learning.id = learning_rel_language.learning_id', 'inner')
            ->join('learning_rel_category', 'learning.id = learning_rel_category.learning_id', 'inner')
            ->where('learning_rel_category.category_id', $c['id'])
            ->where('learning_rel_language.language', $this->language)
            ->group_by('learning_rel_language.language')->get()->first_row('array');

        $metadata = json_decode($c['metadata']);
        $tt = $c['title'];
        $url = $c['url'];
        if($this->language != 'pt_br'){
            $tt = $metadata->{$this->language};
            $tt_pt_br = $c['title'];
        }

        $return[] = array('url' => $url, 'title'=>$tt, 'id'=>$c['id'], 'total'=>$total['total'], 'title_pt_br'=>$tt_pt_br);

    }

    return $return;
}
```

Um detalhe importante que notei no seu estilo de programar: você força seu model a retornar as consultas como array `get()->result_array();` e `get()->first_row('array');` (o padrão do CodIgniter é retornar como objetos), mas quando vai manipular estes dados você força um cast revertendo para trabalhar com objetos `$cat = (object) $cat;` ???? Isso não tem lógica além de ser um desperdício de recursos do servidor. Se vai usar como objeto, não force a saída do model como array, mantenha o padrão do CodeIgniter.